# point-wise transform of `Plot`

Tags: plotting, geometric-transform

Suppose I have the following plot:

```
Plot[(1 - p2)^2/(p2^2 + (1 - p2)^2), {p2, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"p2", "p1"}]
```

[image]

Now I want to do a point-wise transform to every point $(p2,p1)$ on the line (making a new plot) using:

$ p1 \rightarrow \dfrac{p1-\gamma}{1-\gamma}\quad p2\rightarrow\dfrac{p2-\gamma}{1-\gamma} $

In other words, I want to move every point on the line $(p2,p1)$ to a new location $\left(\dfrac{p2-\gamma}{1-\gamma},\dfrac{p1-\gamma}{1-\gamma}\right)$.

How should I achieve that?

Comment: I suppose it is unclear here whether you want to maintain the relationship p2[p1] as defined in your original plot. Should p2 become (p2[p1] - gamma)/(1- gamma) -or- (p2[(p1-gamma)/(1-gamma)] - gamma)/(1- gamma) ?

Comment: @CoreyKelly, no, I don't need that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you *did* want to transform the plot, you can use something like:

```
Manipulate[
    Plot[(1 - p2)^2/(p2^2 + (1 - p2)^2), {p2, 0, 1},
         AxesLabel -> {"p2", "p1"}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}] /.
    Line[a__] :> Line @ Map[{(#[[1]] - γ)/(1 - γ), (#[[2]] - γ)/(1 - γ)} &, a],
   {γ, -1, 0.5}]
```

which transforms the points that define the Line.

Comment: Since the relevant functions are `Listable`, I'd do `(# - γ)/(1 - γ) &` myself... for that matter, why not `Line[(a - γ)/(1 - γ)]`?

Answer (score 5):

You *probably* want to transform the function, not the plot:

```
f[p2_] := (1 - p2)^2/(p2^2 + (1 - p2)^2)
Plot[f[p2], {p2, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"p2", "p1"}]
t[p2_, g_] := (f[(p2 - g)/(1 - g)] - g)/(1 - g)
Manipulate[Plot[t[p2, g], {p2, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"p2", "p1"}], {g, 0, 0.999}]
```

[image: Manipulating gamma]

Answer (score 3):

I'd say this is the sort of thing `LinearFractionalTransform[]` was designed for:

```
With[{γ = 2/3}, 
     MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#,
           LinearFractionalTransform[{IdentityMatrix[2], {-γ, -γ}, {0, 0}, 1 - γ}]] &, 
           Plot[(1 - p2)^2/(p2^2 + (1 - p2)^2), {p2, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"p2", "p1"},
                PlotRange -> All], 1]]
```

[image: curve after a linear fractional transformation]

Of course, you can use `ParametricPlot[]` instead of `Plot[]`:

```
With[{γ = 2/3}, 
 ParametricPlot[LinearFractionalTransform[{IdentityMatrix[2], {-γ, -γ}, {0, 0}, 1 - γ}] @ 
                {p2, (1 - p2)^2/(p2^2 + (1 - p2)^2)}, {p2, 0, 1},
                AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, AxesLabel -> {"p2", "p1"}]]
```

Comment: The primary advantage, of course, is you don't have to fiddle with the `PlotRange`. +1

Comment: (I know I could have done the transformation with a judicious combination of translation and scaling, but this seemed more compact.)

Comment: Why do you need the `With` in this case? It seems to work fine without it.

Comment: @Jonathan, I certainly could have made the *global* assignment `γ = 2/3` in before executing the plots, but I prefer not to litter the ``Global` `` context if I can help it. Besides, this is the sort of thing `With[]` is intended for: parameter setting.

Comment: Thanks @J. M., very reasonable.